# Curl error 6 couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to consume a web service. I have my dev environment(laptop) which is on windows, and also a test environment(server) which is on Fedora. **Both share the same internet connection and also the same source code for the application I am testing.**

The current problem

- When I am doing a test **using my dev environment, I get a valid response**
- When I am doing a test **using the test environment, I am getting Curl Error No 6 (could not resolve host)**
- I **can view the WSDL on the test environment using the curl command in the terminal**
- I **can view the WSDL in the browser when I browse it.**
- I have tried the webservice using SOAPUI on my dev environment and I managed to get a valid response as well.
- unfortunately, I cannot find SOAPUI for fedora so I cannot test it on the test environment using SOAPUI.
- I am **able to consume other partner's webservice using test environment.**

Anyone can suggest me what is going on and how to fix it? Whether it is a network problem or the source code?

Below is my source code:

```
    function execute_curl($variables)   //removed variables because its too long
    {
        $this->CI->load->model('mws_transmit_model');

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','SOAPAction:"'.$http_header.'"'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);

        if(isset($ssl_version)):
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, $ssl_version);
        }
        endif;

        if(isset($ca_info)):
        {
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $ca_info);
        }
        endif;

        if(isset($ssl_cert)):
        {
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $ssl_cert);
        }
        endif;

        if(isset($ssl_cert_pass)):
        {
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $ssl_cert_pass);
        }
        endif;

        if(isset($time_out)):
        {
            if($time_out !== "0"):
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $time_out);
            }
            endif;

        }
        endif;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch) == "0"):
        {
            //RETURN SUCCESSFUL CONSUMPTION OF WEB SERVICE
        }
        else:
        {
            //RETURN ERROR
        }
        endif;
    }
```

Comment: are you 100% both environments have the URL for the connection? Is there a config file you could have missed?

Comment: Yes, both have the same URL. The configuration for both file is the same. That is why I find it very weird

Comment: Does your test environment have multiple ips bound to it?

Comment: Somehow yes and no, It has 2 lan card connected to it, 1 to provide LAN connection while the other one to provide internet connection(which I am using for this webservice). but this configuration works before I added functionality in the application(consume multiple webservice)

Comment: Could it be that php is using the wrong interface going out?

Comment: what do you mean? using the connection that has lan connection only? how can we set what connection to use using php?

Comment: @Ponce I know I'm joining the conversation a little too late, but did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I have been encountering the same issue for days now, and there seems to be no known solution to this, and I was kind of anxious to know whether you managed to come out of this.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi, yes. the test server I was using had 2 lan cables connected to the server(1 for internal connection 1 for internet connection), when sending out request it was using the wrong lan cables which uses the wrong connection to server we want to send to that is why it was not able to connect. what we did was remove the other connection and just use one

Comment: @Ponce I see. So basically this was a network issue, right?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi, yes as long as you can ping the server where you want to consume the webservice at the same time you should try SOAPUI if you can invoke it as well

Comment: @Ponce Pinging the said API link fails as well.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi You might want to check the API provider for the valid link. then use SOAPUI first, if it is successful then go for the code.